# Is it possible to push a value into array based on its key

Tags: php, arrays, key, addition

Is it possible to push a value into array based on its key but actually add to the key.

For example

```
$data = array();

    $data[0]= 12;
    $data[1]= 1;
    $data[2]= 2;
    $data[3]= 56;
    $data[4]= 78;

array_push($data, 0,23);
```

so the output would be

```
$data[0]= 35;   (12+23)
$data[1]= 1;
$data[2]= 2;
$data[3]= 56;
$data[4]= 78;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `=`, you can use `+=` to append a value to a variable:

```
$data[0] += 23;
```

This code is equivalent to this:

```
$data[0] = $data[0] + 23;
```

You can see the output here: http://codepad.org/bNruNNFe

Answer (score 4):

Why not `$data[0] += 23`?

Or

Why not `$data[0] = $data[0] + 23`?